# Change len of a list

Tags: python-3.x, list, resize

I have a list as below

`['1024-65535/tcp', '1024-65535/udp']`

I would like to change the len of the list from 2 to one and get some

`[('1024-65535/tcp', '1024-65535/udp')]`
so len 1. I tried resize and also join but they do something else (resizie is cutting out element of list, join give me back a list with len as number of chars that i join). Any suggestion?

Comment: Could you describe your aims & give instances of what you have done & tried? So people could understand your problem.

Comment: I need to compare 2 list. List 1 
'''['4505/tcp', ('4505/tcp', '80/tcp'), '80/tcp', ('80/tcp', '4505/tcp')]
'''
and list_2
''' ['22/tcp', '3172/tcp', '443/tcp', '5900/tcp', '5901/tcp', '5910/tcp', '80/tcp'] '''
I need to find any match between List_1 and List_2.  
Problem is that List_2 consider all its element as single element, on the contrary they need to be a single element (Len 1). Only than i can compare.

Comment: this `[tuple(your_list_name)]` probably does what you want. But it is a **tuple** inside a list and tuples are **immutable**.

Comment: @aspathprepend So you need recursive iteration to compare all internal objects.

Comment: No, compare internal object between 2 list and match  same element works pretty well with intersection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a new list and then turn it to a tuple. After that you can make that tuple again a list.

```
myList = ['1024-65535/tcp', '1024-65535/udp']
newList = [tuple(myList)]
# newList is equal to [('1024-65535/tcp', '1024-65535/udp')]
```